# Python3 image recognition error

Tags: python-3.x

How can I identify this image here: https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000007652899

```
(4412) digital
```

My code is：

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
qq=Image.open('d://frame4.jpg')
text=pytesseract.image_to_string(qq).strip() #使用image_to_string识别验证码
print(text)
```

I would like it to print in English, rather than in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with image array's.
It's not your solution but here is an example :

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

book_a = Image.open('booka.png')
book_b = Image.open('bookb.png')

#Which image do you like to compare?
input = book_b  #book_a of book_b

print('*** Numpy array Book A')

book_a_ar = np.asarray(book_a)
print(book_a_ar)

print('*** Numpy array Book B')

book_b_ar = np.asarray(book_b)
print(book_b_ar)

#BOOK C is in use to compare those images

print('*** Numpy array Book C')
book_C_ar = np.asarray(input)
print(book_C_ar)

#compare

if np.all(book_b_ar == book_C_ar):
    print('True')

else:
    print('False')
```

Also take a look at this: [Microcontrollers](https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_KNN_Character_Recognition_Python)